# Encircle react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native

I want to encircle react-native-vector icons. I have added a border radius in the style but it not helpful for all devices and also with every icon it behaves different.

```
    <Icon  name={'ios-grid-outline'} style={{ color: "rgb(170, 207, 202)", 
 borderRadius:10,
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: 'rgb(170, 207, 202)',
}} />
```

Link to react native vector icons:
https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your expected behaviour and actual behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the `overflow:"hidden"` option to your style

```
<Icon  name={'ios-grid-outline'} style={{ 
  color: "rgb(170, 207, 202)", 
  borderRadius:10,
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: 'rgb(170, 207, 202)',
  overflow: "hidden"
}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap it inside a `View` as a container

```
<View 
    style={{
        width: 10, 
        height: 10, 
        borderRadius: 5, 
        borderWidth: 2, 
        borderColor: 'rgb(170, 207, 202)'
    }}>
    <Icon name={'ios-grid-outline'} style={{...}} />
</View>
```

Change the width and height to your own preference of course.

Comment: Although your answer is possible solution to the problem, the [`Icon`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#icon-component) component is probably from `react-native-vector-icons` library like the question suggests.

Comment: Good catch, I will update my answer to be more specific to that.

Comment: Thank you but it is showing different on different screen sizes. As I have to adjust the height and width according to the screen orientation. Even at some screens icons moves out from the center of circle. I have added the image above.

Comment: How are you adjusting the height and width on the component?